# RANDBETWEEN in excel

Tags: excel

This is driving me nuts. I want to generate a random number in excel but in the following format

+++522/7226/61416+++

So I need 3 blocks of numbers randomly generated
1ste block = `RANDBETWEEN(0;999)`
2nd block = `RANDBETWEEN(0;9999)`
3rd block = `RANDBETWEEN(0;99999)`

I know how RANDBETWEEN works but I can't to get it working with the +++ and the /

Answer (score 4):

How using **&** and **" "** to include strings:

```
="+++"& TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;999);"000")&"/"&TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;9999);"0000")&"/"&TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;99999);"00000")&"+++"
```

Even more efficient is Ron's suggestion below:

```
=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(1;999999999999);"+++000\/0000\/00000+++")
```

Comment: No :( I get the message...You've entered to few arguments for this function.

Comment: I did something similar, but will randbetween always give 3 numbers? I suggest randbetween(0,9)&randbetween(0,9)&randbetween(0,9) etc Or another idea is randbetween(100,999) - should always provide 3 numbers that way.

Comment: I think you are using semicolons as delimiters. Replace all commas by semicolons .

Comment: Sorry my mistake....you use "," and I need to use ";"...It works, thanks a million. I thought I've tried this before but I forgot "=" to start with...donout I am :)

Comment: @SolarMike Just use TEXT() `="+++"& TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(0;999),"000")&"/"`

Comment: Good point guys, thanks! I updated the function with @ScottCraner 's suggestion.

Comment: @ScottCraner neat solution , mine was brute force in comparison! will remember that...

Comment: @VBAPete You can also put it all into a single `TEXT` function:  `=TEXT(RANDBETWEEN(1,999999999999),"+++000\/0000\/00000+++")`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks, very efficient solution! I added it to my answer.

Comment: @VBAPete I overlooked that the OP is using semicolons as the separator, and I used commas.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Fixed :)

Comment: It's not clear if `RandBetween` will produce a uniform distribution over that many (12) digits.  I suspect it may be limited to 32 bit (2,147,483,647) and so would leave some numbers out when ranged to 999,999,999,999

Comment: @chrisneilsen I don't `RANDBETWEEN` is limited to 32 bit. When I tested the function I got values higher than 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @vba Yes, in Excel it does (in VBA it _is_ limited to 32 bit) .  Just because it returns a result doesn't mean it can return _all_ numbers between 0 and 999,999,999,999.  I suspect there may be some scaling going on